# nonlinearTest() in S-plus vs R

Tags: r, threshold, splus

Is there any similar function in R does the same thing as nonlinearTest() in S-plus? I am currently working on determine the number of regimes,delayed parameter d and threshold values for the threshold value.  Or otherwise where can I download a student S-plus? Do I have to use the university computer in order to free download?

Comment: Questions about where to download software - even if it would be legal for you to do so - are off-topic here.

Comment: What does `nonlinearTest` do in Splus?

Comment: You can fit SETAR and related models in R, and there are some tests of nonlinearity. See the section on Nonlinear Time Series Analysis in the [*Time Series* Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html) which mentions several packages.

Comment: Hey I used tsDyn to fit a threshold model :) It does the same thing as nonlinearTest :)